# No automatic update using the Beta test in the Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I have configured the open beta tests in the Google Play Store using a link like `https://play.google.com/apps/testing/<my app package name>` to invite my users to join the beta.

The users can download the app but when a new update is available the users didn't receive the update. Why ?

The only way for the users to download the update is going in the Play Store page of my app and click on the **update** button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem beta apps doesn't have the same update system than published app.